# Create a Schema from an existing one?

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

I have two databases:

1. database A with missing indexes,constraints,foreign keys etc ...
2. database B  with all the missing features

I have  loaded the schemas of the two databases in my C# code and after comparing them I added the missing features to the first schema.
Now I want to update that schema back to SQL Server. How to do that? Could I create a schema from an existing schema?

This is what I have tried:

```
public static void Compare(ref DbMetaData dbSchema , ref DbMetaData dbSchema2)
{

    foreach (var schemaGroup in dbSchema.SchemasDic.Values )
    {
        DbUserSchemaInfo schemaGroup2=dbSchema2.SchemasDic.Values.First(sc => sc.SchemaName == schemaGroup.SchemaName);

        foreach (var x in schemaGroup.TablesDic)
        {
            var y = schemaGroup2.TablesDic.First(sc => sc.Value.TableName == x.Value.TableName);
            // GET the difference in columns
            var colDiff = x.Value.Columns.Except(y.Value.Columns);
            // GET the difference in indexes
            var indexDiff = x.Value.Indexes.Except(y.Value.Indexes);
            // GET the difference in constraints
            var constraintDiff = x.Value.DfConstraints.Except(y.Value.DfConstraints);
            // GET the difference in Fk
            var foreignKeysDiff = x.Value.ForeignKeys.Except(y.Value.ForeignKeys);
            //check if a primary key exists
            var primaryKeysDiff = y.Value.PrimaryKey == null ? x.Value.PrimaryKey : null;
            // GET the difference in triggers
           var triggersDiff = x.Value.Triggers.Except(y.Value.Triggers);

            //merge the difference
            if (indexDiff.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (var index in indexDiff)
                {
                    y.Value.AddTableIndex(index.Value);
                }
            }
            if (constraintDiff.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (var constraint in constraintDiff)
                {
                    y.Value.AddDefaultConstraint(constraint.Value);
                }
            }
            if (foreignKeysDiff.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (var foreignKey in foreignKeysDiff)
                {
                    y.Value.AddFk(foreignKey.Value);
                }
            }
            if (triggersDiff.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (var trigger in triggersDiff)
                {
                    y.Value.AddTableTrigger(trigger.Value);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    //Update DbSchema in sqlserver
}
```

Comment: Consider creating a database project using [SQL Server Data Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/ssdt/).

Comment: Adding to the comment by @gvee, the SSDT schema compare tool in VS allows you to compare 2 physical databases and select differences to apply to the target. You can then either apply changes immediately or generate a script to do so.

Comment: This is not something you want to be implementing in code, there are several tools that already do schema comparisons between databases and create migration scripts, such as from xsql, Redgate and others.